# Creating a folder in Android External Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-storage

I  would like to create a directory in /storage/emulated/0/ and a save a file there.Since the "getExternalStorageDir()" & "getExternalPublicStorageDir()" are Depreciated I don't know how to implement it.
I have gone through most of the questions and answers but they are all either outdated/open.
All I want is a way to access the "storage/emulated/0/" path.

```
val extStorageDirectory = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
val folder = File(extStorageDirectory, "Work Logs")
folder.mkdir()
```

The above code creates a folder in "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files"

Comment: `folder.mkdir()` Only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call it check the return value as it will return false if the directory could not be created. You should return then and display a toast to inform the user.

Comment: `I want a copy or the orginal file there in Downloads directory (or) a directory for my app on the external storage.` Ok. But that does not match the subject of your post.

Comment: You better post the code for that what you want to do but did not work.

Comment: @blackapps ok I will edit the question!

Comment: I want to create a directory in "/storage/emulated/0/" @blackapps

Comment: You have not updated the code concerning mkdir(). Further you should use the right path in your code.

Comment: sir I have asked an entirely new question in my profile. I request you to visit that.

Comment: Can be but we are here now.

Comment: ok sir I will edit this whole question in a minute.

Comment: `The above code creates a folder in "Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/"` No. It creates a folder in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files`